# Проблемы с типом "char" в lua ffi после подгрузки "sys/types.h"

Tags: lua

Я использую ffib и lcpp (с моим искателем). После подгрузки заголовков из `<sys/types.h>`, вместо `char` начинают создаваться `int` массивы и переменные.

Выглядит это дело так:

```
th> ffi.new('char[10]')
cdata<char[10]>: 0x2366d98
                                                                      [0.0002s]
th> ffi.cdef[[#include <sys/types.h>]]
                                                                      [0.7561s]
th> ffi.new('char[10]')
cdata<int[10]>: 0x25bf3a8
```

В чём дело в этой библиотеке?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если не представиться компилятором, то библиотека слишком умничает, и переопределяет `char` как `int`. Это просто решается тремя `define`-ами:

```
ffi.cdef [[#define __GNUC__ 5
#define __GNUC_MINOR__ 1
#define __STDC__ 1]]
```